# Make OneToOneField visible in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models. `Language` and `Quiz`. Since the `Quiz` is a model of third party app, I've added `OneToOneField(Quiz)` into my `Language` model (otherwise I did the opposite).

Since the `OneToOneField` is defined in `Language`, I can see in `Language` tab in Django admin `model choise form` for `Quiz` instances.

How could make it work opposite? I mean that I want to be able to choose `Language` in `Quiz` admin tab instead of choosing `Quiz` in `Language` tab.

[image]

I tried some changes in `admin.py` but none of them worked:

```
    class QuizInlineLanguage(admin.StackedInline):
        model = Language

    class QuizAdmin(ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [QuizInlineLanguage,]

admin.site.register(Quiz,QuizAdmin)
```

The code above does not work. It adds two additional forms (which belongs to Language but it's not Language model choose form) into the `Quiz` tab.

Do you know what to do?

Comment: It's not straight forward to edit a one-to-one, foreign key or many-to-many field on the other model. Inlines are the closest thing that Django has out of the box. If that's not good enough, then it's going to take a bit of custom code (e.g. a custom model form, and a custom model admin that uses that form).

Comment: Inline would be good enough probably, but I don't want to put the inner forms of Language model into Quiz admin, I want to put Language instances choose form into the Quiz admin (added picture above). Is it possible?

Comment: The thing I want in fact, is to add Language model choice into the Quiz model. So I can choose from Languages in Quiz admin. But it's third party app so It is not appropriate to change Quiz model itself.

Comment: you mean 'admin.ModelAdmin.related_lookup_fields' ? then, you can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018022/related-lookup-field-foreign-key-doesnt-work-in-inline-django)